# Latest Code not exericed inDebugging with Dot.Net

Tags: .net, debugging

I have a .NET solution with a bunch of projects. The Main Project is a Windows Form Project. Most of my changes are in a class library project that is being instanced by the Main Project.

When I make a change to the Class Library project. The old code is exercised. When I step through in debug the new code is shown by the old code is actually performed.

I've seen several suggestions in other threads but none of them work constantly. Eventually the new code starts working but I'm not sure what I do to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This should not happen. Make sure you referenced the class library as a *project reference*, not just as a link to the file on disc. That way, VS will rebuild both projects if there are changes.

If that's the case and you still have problems that old code is used (which I have difficulties to believe, that would be a VS bug) make sure that you "clean" and "rebuild all" before each debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the properties for the solution, there was a tab Debug Source Files. Under the list "Do not look for these source files" was the module I was changing. I remove it from the list and the problem went away.

I don't know how it got in the list in the first place.

Bob